# When the browser request a script ( dynamically generated by PHP ) i get a 404 but if i go directly there it works

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

i'm generating my javascript in PHP. If i include a script tag like this

```
<script src="http://www.everythingpuntagorda.com/blog?ai1ec_render_js=common_backend&amp;is_backend=true&amp;is_calendar_page&amp;ver=1.11.1-pro" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the browser return a 404

[image]

but if you go to http://www.everythingpuntagorda.com/blog?ai1ec_render_js=common_backend&is_backend=true&is_calendar_page&ver=1.11.1-pro

you'll see that the javascript is created as expected. This is our .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

#BEGIN HG BLOCK 
#order deny,allow 
#allow from 74.202.255.240/29 
#allow from 216.110.94.176/28 
#allow from 216.110.94.224/27 
#allow from 199.187.122.66 
#allow from 199.187.122.67 
#allow from 78.46.70.238 
#allow from 204.187.12.90 
#allow from 74.86.15.72 
#allow from 180.149.241.242 
#allow from 175.107.133.185 
#allow from 217.27.250.160 
#allow from 174.58.72.114 
#allow from 66.87.109.196 
#deny from all 
#END HG BLOCK

# BEGIN WPSuperCache 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
#If you serve pages from behind a proxy you may want to change 'RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on' to something more sensible 
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.* 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(2.0\ MMP|240x320|400X240|AvantGo|BlackBerry|Blazer|Cellphone|Danger|DoCoMo|Elaine/3.0|EudoraWeb|Googlebot-Mobile|hiptop|IEMobile|KYOCERA/WX310K|LG/U990|MIDP-2.|MMEF20|MOT-V|NetFront|Newt|Nintendo\ Wii|Nitro|Nokia|Opera\ Mini|Palm|PlayStation\ Portable|portalmmm|Proxinet|ProxiNet|SHARP-TQ-GX10|SHG-i900|Small|SonyEricsson|Symbian\ OS|SymbianOS|TS21i-10|UP.Browser|UP.Link|webOS|Windows\ CE|WinWAP|YahooSeeker/M1A1-R2D2|iPhone|iPod|Android|BlackBerry9530|LG-TU915\ Obigo|LGE\ VX|webOS|Nokia5800).* [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_user_agent} !^(w3c\ |w3c-|acs-|alav|alca|amoi|audi|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-|dang|doco|eric|hipt|htc_|inno|ipaq|ipod|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-|lg/u|maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|palm|pana|pant|phil|play|port|prox|qwap|sage|sams|sany|sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo|teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|wap-|wapa|wapi|wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda\ |xda-).* [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blog/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html.gz -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/blog/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html.gz" [L]

</IfModule>

# END WPSuperCache

# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This is the function that generates the javascript

```
/**
 * Render the javascript for the appropriate page
 * 
 */
public function render_js() {
    header( 'Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8' );
    // Aggressive caching to save future requests from the same client.
    $etag = '"' . md5( __FILE__ . $_GET[self::LOAD_JS_PARAMETER] ) . '"';
    header( 'ETag: ' . $etag );
    $max_age = 31536000;// One Year
    header(
        'Expires: ' .
        gmdate(
            'D, d M Y H:i:s',
            Ai1ec_Time_Utility::current_time() + $max_age
        ) .
        ' GMT'
    );
    header( 'Cache-Control: public, max-age=' . $max_age );
    if (
        empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) ||
        $etag !== stripslashes( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] )
    ) {
        // compress data if possible
        if ( true === extension_loaded( 'zlib' ) ) {
            ob_start( 'ob_gzhandler' );
            header( 'Content-Encoding: gzip' );
        } else {
            ob_start();
        }

        $js_path = AI1EC_ADMIN_THEME_JS_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $common_js = '';
        $page_to_load = $_GET[self::LOAD_JS_PARAMETER];

        if ( $_GET[self::IS_BACKEND_PARAMETER] === self::TRUE_PARAM ) {
            $common_js = file_get_contents( $js_path . 'pages/common_backend.js' );
        } else if( $page_to_load === self::EVENT_PAGE_JS ||
            $page_to_load === self::CALENDAR_PAGE_JS || 
            $page_to_load === self::LOAD_ONLY_FRONTEND_SCRIPTS ) {
            if ( $page_to_load === self::LOAD_ONLY_FRONTEND_SCRIPTS &&
                true === self::$frontend_scripts_loaded ) {
                return;
            }
            if ( false === self::$frontend_scripts_loaded ) {
                $common_js = file_get_contents( $js_path . 'pages/common_frontend.js' );
                self::$frontend_scripts_loaded = true;
            }

        }
        // create the config object for require js
        $require_config = $this->create_require_js_config_object();
        // load require
        $require = file_get_contents( $js_path . 'require.js' );

        // get jquery
        $jquery = $this->get_jquery_version_based_on_browser( 
            $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
        );
        // load the script for the page

        $page_js = '';
        if ( $page_to_load !== self::LOAD_ONLY_BACKEND_SCRIPTS &&
             $page_to_load !== self::LOAD_ONLY_FRONTEND_SCRIPTS
        ) {
            $page_js = file_get_contents( $js_path . 'pages/' . $page_to_load );
        }


        $translation = $this->get_frontend_translation_data();
        $permalink = get_permalink( $this->settings->calendar_page_id );

        $translation['calendar_url'] = $permalink;

        $tranlsation_module = $this->create_require_js_module( 
            self::FRONTEND_CONFIG_MODULE, 
            $translation 
        );
        $config = $this->create_require_js_module(
            'ai1ec_config',
            $this->get_translation_data()
        );
        echo $require . $require_config . $tranlsation_module . 
                $config . $jquery . $page_js . $common_js;
        ob_end_flush();
    } else {
        // Not modified!
        status_header( 304 );
    }
    // We're done!
    ai1ec_stop( 0 );
}
```

i had our sysadmin look at this with no effect

Comment: What response header do you set in the php script?

Comment: @n1te i added the php function, anyway i set 
header( 'Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8' );

Comment: The created JavaScript file is sending the 404 for some reason. Are you sure it's not in the PHP somewhere? It would have to be before the ETag however...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding this in the php that returns the javascript:

```
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
    header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
    echo "your javascript goes here";
```

Comment: This will probably fix the problem, but I'd still be curious as to why the 404 was sent in the first place.

Comment: @Pekka웃 i'll try this but why if i click the link i don't get a 404?I should get a 404 in the browser too, right?

Comment: @Nicola you *are* getting a 404 status code when you click the link. Look at the response headers in your element inspector.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti 404 is just the HTTP header, you can still serve content after that

Comment: This is your response:

`HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
X-Pingback: http://www.everythingpuntagorda.com/blog/xmlrpc.php
Pragma: no-cache
ETag: "6b30a8d49fb20f026d46b7033d64fc51"
Cache-Control: private, max-age=31536000
Set-Cookie: wfvt_3571172157=51d429c23d956; expires=Wed, 03-Jul-2013 14:10:18 GMT; path=/
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
Date: Wed, 03 Jul 2013 13:40:18 GMT
Expires: Wed, 03 Jul 2013 13:40:18 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 45145
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block`

Comment: Hi, this worked. This is a wordpress plugin so anything can put a 404 before our plugin executes, who knows

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti happy to help. Headers with wordpress are always a pain